# How to marshal Link-local ipv6 address into XML

Tags: java, xml, ipv6

I am trying to use 'com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal' to do XML marshal action, but it report an error for an IPv6 address format:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'https://[fe80::b93c:f0eb:b8a9:aad3%11]:8443' is not a valid value for 'anyURI'
```

The IPv6 Link-local address which has zone id with it caused this error report. if I remove the zone id and use `https://[fe80::b93c:f0eb:b8a9:aad3]:8443` then there will not report error while doing marshal.

But I think the Link-Local Address with zone id should not report as error format. How can I make the 'marshal` not throw error while meet this address?

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is but looking at the error message and the ip6 address you presented. There seems to be "%11" in the original address?

Comment: In the URI, the % use for 'Escaped Encoding', but in ipv6 link local address it must has this % ... I try to use `https://[fe80::b93c:f0eb:b8a9:aad3%2511]:8443` but it still report error that not not a valid value for 'anyURI' ...

Comment: So do you think the problem is with ip6 address? Can a domain name be defined in the hosts file so that you do not need to escape? What about using ip4 address just to eliminate its not the issue somewhere else?

Comment: Hi, @MinhKieu , Yes, in most case we can use the host name or ipv4 . But my problem was that why the standard ipv6 address couldn't use while marshal it into an XML...

Comment: I would say that would be your workaround for now. Its looks like the SAXParser is not compatible with IP6 addresses. Not sure if the latest version do and whether it is easily get upgraded.

Comment: Thank you! @MinhKieu.  I found a RFC-6874 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6874 that update the URI format to support IPV6 Link-Local address with zone id. Maybe I should try to upgrade the SAXPaeser to see whether they fix this. But could someone help to tell me how to upgrade the SAXParser or change they to use a new version of 'cvc-datatype-valid'? Current it was 1.21 bu default in java 1.8.0.